# How to put in Info.plist 2 <key>CFBundleURLTypes</key>

Tags: ios, firebase, google-cloud-platform, nativescript, info.plist

I want to use authentication from google and facebook, [plugin](https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/nativescript-plugin-firebase/blob/master/docs/AUTHENTICATION.md)

I want to put in Info.plist

for google:

```
<key>CFBundleURLTypes</key>
    <array>
        <dict>
            <key>CFBundleTypeRole</key>
            <string>Editor</string>
            <key>CFBundleURLName</key>
            <string>REVERSED_CLIENT_ID</string>
            <key>CFBundleURLSchemes</key>
            <array>
                <string>com.googleusercontent.apps.1052836194035-l81fsjai1u40ocnqjcpnoebnnsltt03b</string>
            </array>
        </dict>
    </array>
```

for facebook:

```
<key>CFBundleURLTypes</key>
<array>
  <dict>
    <key>CFBundleURLSchemes</key>
    <array>
      <string>fb{your-app-id}</string>
    </array>
  </dict>
</array>
<key>FacebookAppID</key>
<string>{your-app-id}</string>
<key>FacebookDisplayName</key>
<string>{your-app-name}</string>
<key>LSApplicationQueriesSchemes</key>
<array>
  <string>fbapi</string>
  <string>fb-messenger-share-api</string>
  <string>fbauth2</string>
  <string>fbshareextension</string>
</array>
```

How to use both in one Info.plist?

When I remove CFBundleURLTypes in facebook, in console show error: Missing key while parsing

Any idea please?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Club the entities under the same key as following:
(You can use the following)

```
<key>CFBundleURLTypes</key>
    <array>
        <dict>
            <key>CFBundleTypeRole</key>
            <string>Editor</string>
            <key>CFBundleURLName</key>
            <string>REVERSED_CLIENT_ID</string>
            <key>CFBundleURLSchemes</key>
            <array>
                <string>com.googleusercontent.apps.1052836194035-l81fsjai1u40ocnqjcpnoebnnsltt03b</string>
               <string>fb{your-app-id}</string>
            </array>
        </dict>
    </array>
<key>FacebookAppID</key>
<string>{your-app-id}</string>
<key>FacebookDisplayName</key>
<string>{your-app-name}</string>
<key>LSApplicationQueriesSchemes</key>
<array>
  <string>fbapi</string>
  <string>fb-messenger-share-api</string>
  <string>fbauth2</string>
  <string>fbshareextension</string>
</array>
```